# find field pattern in a csv file then count unique field values

Tags: grep, search, csv-simple

I am using Cygwin (bash) to create a script to find, group and count fields in multiple CSV files. Each row will have comma-separated fields with each field following a similar convention. There is a numeric value, then an equal sign (=), then an alphanumeric value. The "(number)=" may or may not be present in a row and, if present, the field position may vary, but appear only once in the row. In addition, the value after the equal sign will vary in length.

An example of my objective will be best.
CSV File:

```
35=D,11=ABCD1,1=ABC,55=XYZ,38=100,40=P,18=M,54=1,59=0,10=111
35=D,11=ABCD2,1=ABC,55=XYZ,38=200,40=P,18=M,54=1,44=10.00,59=0,10=133
35=D,11=ABCD3,1=ABC,55=XYZ,38=300,40=P,18=M B,54=1,44=10.00,59=0,110=200,10=113
35=D,11=ABCD4,1=ABC,55=XYZ,38=400,40=P,18=M B F,54=1,44=10.00,59=0,110=300,10=144
35=D,11=ABCD5,1=ABC,55=ZYX,38=300,40=2,54=1,44=10.00,59=3,10=132
35=D,11=ABCD6,1=ABC,55=QQQ,38=100,40=1,18=C,54=2,59=3,10=131
```

The "18=" field values are space-separated. I would like to have a script or one-liner that would identify each unique "18=" value and then count the appearance of each. The output using the above file would be (sort is optional):

```
18=M 2
18=M B 1
18=M B F 1
18=C 1
```

As mentioned, this script should read a number of files with records in this format. I have tried different `grep` combinations and dabbled with `awk`, but I am less familiar with its proper implementation.

The first two answers do work (thanks a lot!). Would it be possible to expand to aggregate the "38=" values grouped by the unique "18=" count results?

Comment: You should not change or expand your question with additional constraints as it invalidates the existing answers. Put up a new question if commenting to the answerers is helping you out. Questions are **not** the place for feedback. You read the help-tour: "no distractions, no chit-chat"

Answer (score 1):

This is probably best done in Perl with a hash structure:

```
perl -nle '($x)=/(18=[^,]+)/;$y{$x}++; END{print "$_ $y{$_}" for keys %y}' files
```

**Explanation**

For each line, Perl looks for `18=` followed by as many non-comma characters as possible; whatever it finds, it stores in the variable `$x`. This variable is then used as a key to the hash `%y`, whose associated value is incremented for each key `$x` found.

At the very `END` (*i.e.*, after all lines have been processed), we print the keys (`18=...` fields) and associated values (number of occurrences) of the hash variable `%y`.

Answer (score 1):

Do you try the combination?

```
grep -ho "18=[^,]*" list_of_files | sort | uniq -c
```